# PHP: Separate MySQL query values with a comma

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL query like this written in PHP:

```
$merkki = $_GET["merkki"];
// Retrieve all the data from the table 
//to show models based on selection of manufacturer

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Control_Mallit WHERE merkki_id = $merkki")
or die(mysql_error()); 
echo '{';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '"' . $row['id'] . '"' . ":" . '"' . $row['malli'] . '"';
}
echo '}';
```

Result is correct, but how I can get a comma after each record?  If I echo (,) after each row my code doesn't work. I need it formatted as described below.

```
{
    "":"--",
    "series-1":"1 series",
    "series-3":"3 series",
    "series-5":"5 series",
    "series-6":"6 series",
    "series-7":"7 series"
}
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Immediately* stop using your code. It is vulnerable to SQL injection. Think of what would happen if the value of `merkki` was `1 OR 1=1`. The statement would return all records:

```
SELECT * FROM Control_Mallit WHERE merkki_id = 1 OR 1=1
```

You need to bind parameters to your query using `mysqli_` or `PDO` functions (`mysql_` functions are [being deprecated](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql). Also, use a column list and do not `SELECT *`.

Here is a possible solution using `mysqli_` (not tested):

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');

/* check connection */
if (!$link) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$array = array();

/* create a prepared statement */
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT id, malli FROM Control_Mallit WHERE merkki_id = ?");

/* bind parameters for markers */
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'i', $_GET[merkki]);

/* execute query */
$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

/* fetch associative array */
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array[] = '"' . $row['id'] . '"' . ":" . '"' . $row['malli'] . '"';
}

/* free result set */
mysqli_free_result($result);

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);

echo '{' . implode(',', $array) . '}';

?>
```

---

**Edit**

Following your original code, this solution should work:

```
$merkki = $_GET["merkki"];
$array = array();
// Retrieve all the data from the table to show models based on selection of manufacturer
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Control_Mallit WHERE merkki_id = $merkki")
or die(mysql_error()); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $array[] = '"' . $row['id'] . '"' . ":" . '"' . $row['malli'] . '"';
}
echo '{' . implode(',', $array) . '}';
```

Comment: Thank you for fast answer. I couldn't get this to work, but got good feedback. I have to learn about mysqli or PDO.

Comment: @SamuPalomäki I've edited my answer and included a solution based on your original code.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just stick everything in an array and use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to output it, eg

```
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $data[$row['id']] = $row['malli'];
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Small example here - http://codepad.viper-7.com/My27XJ

Also, you should not be using the deprecated `mysql` extension. Instead, I recommend PDO, eg

```
$db = new PDO(/* connection details */);
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT id, malli FROM Control_Mallit WHERE merkki_id = ?');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_GET['merkki']);
$stmt->execute();

while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // and so on
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$merkki = $_GET["merkki"];
$merkki = mysql_real_escape_string($merkki);

// Retrieve all the data from the table to show models based on selection of manufacturer
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Control_Mallit WHERE merkki_id = $merkki")
or die(mysql_error());
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$row = 1;
echo '{';
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo '"' . $row['id'] . '"' . ":" . '"' . $row['malli'] . '"';
    if ($row < $numRows) {
        echo ',';
    }
    $row++;
}
echo '}';
```

It just uses the row count to determine if it should echo a comma or not based on whether or not it is on the last result.

Also, be sure to escape any input you pass to mysql queries or you are vulnerable to SQL injection.  See about switching to PDO or Mysqli in the future.

Comment: Edited it a little and got it working. Now to change my codes to mysqli or PDO, have to learn that tomorrow. Thank you for your fast answer. I edited that $row counter variable name to $rivi and it worked after that.